# Unexpected behavior with button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I use the next code in my react render function:

```
<button>
  <img
    src="./assets/iconspng/icons8-create-50.png"
    alt="Edit Pilot Application"
    onClick={this.buttonAction}
  />
  Show Clients Info                                     
</button>
```

The problem I have is that to run the action   this.buttonAction  I can only click on the picture loaded by  icons8-create-50.png  . If I click at the label  'Show Clients Info'  nothing happens. I need to be able to click on both the label and the picture to make the action run. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `onClick` on the `button` instead?

Comment: Are you referring to   onClick={this.buttonAction}?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Move that entire piece of code.

Comment: hahahah... I think I know what you men,,,, boy!! Let me try

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga - If you want to delete the question, let me know, I can delete the answer below, which will allow you to do so.

Comment: Some mistakes better to share... I know I got -2 but this is a mistake that I can't believe I made...

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga - Your call, but FWIW, I don't think this will really be all that helpful to others in the fugure. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks a lot... this is a mistake I will love to remember forever... coding late at night can be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I have is that to run the action this.buttonAction I can only click on the picture loaded by icons8-create-50.png . If I click at the label 'Show Clients Info' nothing happens.

That's because the `onClick` is on the *image*, not the button. So clicking the label doesn't fire it.

Put the `onClick` on the `button`, not the `img`. (If the user clicks the `img`, it'll propagate to the `button`.)

```
<button onClick={this.buttonAction}>
  <img
    src="./assets/iconspng/icons8-create-50.png"
    alt="Edit Pilot Application"
  />
  Show Clients Info                                     
</button>
```